# Poorly rendered text (NSFont) in MacRuby/Cocoa. Any advice?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nstextview, macruby

I have a small MacRuby app that displays some text inside a `NSTextView`. I have a method called `make_label()` that builds an NSTextView with some text and returns it, which I use to add to another NSView via `addSubview()`

`make_label()` looks like this:

```
def make_label( x, y, width, height, color, font_size, text )
  label = NSTextView.alloc.initWithFrame( NSMakeRect( x, y, width, height) )
  font = NSFont.systemFontOfSize(font_size)
  label.setFont( font )
  label.insertText( text )
  label.setTextColor( color )
  label.setDrawsBackground(false)
  label.setRichText(true)
  label.setEditable(false)
  label.setSelectable(false)
  label
end
```

My question is, how come my text looks so poorly rendered? It looks very pixelated and not antialiased at all (from what I can see).

### [Click here for screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bgandlala/6362562717/in/photostream)

This screenshot shows 2 different sizes of the font, with the same phenomenon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit was `setWantsLayer(true)` which was called for the view I was drawing in. I deleted that line and I also needed to `label.setDrawsBackground(false)` as joerick described.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa can't draw sub-pixel antialiased text if it's rendering to a context that isn't opaque.

I come from the objective-C side, so I'm guessing a bit, but try setting `label.setDrawsBackground(false)` to true.

Comment: Unfortunately, same results. Also, note that I am drawing this text on top of an `NSImage` (if this helps at all). Hiding the image doesn't help, though.